# How can I add sourceset to jar file?

Tags: build, intellij-idea, gradle

I've defined custom sourceset but `gradle build` doesn't include its sources to jar file + `gradle idea` doesn't mark `srcDir` as `Sources`.
How can I configure gradle proper way?

Here is an example:

```
sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'
    }
}

api {
    java {
        srcDir 'api'
    }
}
}
```

In this case `gradle build` will build only `main` source set (classes from `src` directory) and skip `api` source set. Similar problem for `gradle idea` - only `src` dir will be marked as `Sources`

Answer (score 4):

And finally 8 year later I've got the correct answer.

```
// Let's the default resource generation depend on your sourset's resource generation.
processResources.dependsOn( processApiResources )

// Inherit the standard configuraton. You need to change this is want to have a different configuration for this sources.
configurations {
    apiCompile.extendsFrom mainCompile
    apiRuntime.extendsFrom mainRuntime
}

jar {
    // Add directories with generated sources (might be several - one for every supported language).
    from sourceSets.api.output.classesDirs
    // Add output directories of the sourceset's resources.
    from sourceSets.api.output.resourcesDir
}
```

Comment: For me, `jar { from sourceSets.api.output }` was enough.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you would only declare a separate source set if you also wanted to keep its outputs separate. Otherwise, you can just add another source directory to the "main" source set:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "src"
            srcDir "api"
        }
    }
}
```

This will also mark "api" as a source directory in IDEA.

Comment: Let's assume that I really need separate source set. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Configure the `jar` task and `idea.module` extension accordingly. For details see the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).